# Липкая панель на bootsrap3

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap

Есть такой код

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вставляю я его перед

```
</body>
</html>
```

Но я не вижу содержимого.
По идее должен получиться плавающий стик - что я делаю не так?

Пробую редактировать тему WordPress, если нужно куда-то выложить больше - всегда готов.
Пример брал тут https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/trybs_affix_vertical_nav.htm

Спасибо.

Comment: а все ли элементы бутстрапа у Вас правильно подключены? подключена ли библиотека jQuery?

Comment: jquery.js
jquery-migrate.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
page-scroll.js
carousel.js
jquery-ui.min.js

Подключено, подозреваю что стик не откреплен от общей сетки, но не знаю как открепить

Comment: Если вы вставляете именно в таком виде,
тогда я полагаю что у вас просто на html или body висит overflow
А так как этот элемент позиционирован и результата вы не видите 
Потому что он просто вне зоны видимости

Comment: а как можно тогда поступить?

Comment: css для .affix стоит? При прокрутке класс меняется (js срабатывает) ? В консоле есть ошибки?